# Appending items to a column of vectors in R

Tags: r

I have two data frames, one with a list of unique subject ids (length 39) and one with a list of subject ids repeated if subjects participated in multiple trials. I would like to

Basically, I need to go from this:

```
a 23
a 33
a 18
b 90
b 2
```

to this:

```
a [23, 33, 18] 
b [90, 2]
```

I've been working at this pathetically for a couple hours and would love any help I can get!

I've tried a million things and none of them seem to work!

```
for (i in 1:39) {

   for (j in 1:119) {

      if (datafram1$ids[i] == datafram2$ids[j]) datafram1$cases[i] <- append(datafram1$cases[i],datafram2$scores[j])

   }

}
```

results in the following warning:
number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe store it as a list:

```
dat <- read.table(text="a 23
a 33
a 18
b 90
b 2", header=FALSE)

with(dat, tapply(V2, V1, c))

## $a
## [1] 23 33 18
## 
## $b
## [1] 90  2
```

If you want it to look like your output:

```
FUN <- function(x) paste0("[", paste(x, collapse=", "), "]")

aggregate(V2~V1, dat, FUN)
##   V1           V2
## 1  a [23, 33, 18]
## 2  b      [90, 2]
```